# multidimensional computation using pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

We are currently using 3 different dataframes to store product,performance and assortments data.
The foreign key relationship is maintained between all the dimensions.

I need to update the cost column in the performance by doing the below math operation

```
performance['cost'] = performance['coulmn1']+sin(product['column3'])+2*Assortment['column2']
```

I need this operation to be performed for each row of the performance dataframe.

Please suggest any approach to make the calculations faster.
The performance dataframe consists of 1 million records.

Can we use any other approach rather than dataframe??

Comment: Is the formula you wrote the actual way you are doing it now (which is **highly effective**), or just the formula you want to implement and not sure how? If you need help in implementing it, please add to the question the `header`s of the `dataframe`s you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach could be to pre-calculate the sin function for the entire column. I used 1million records for it and it was pretty fast for me.

```
import pandas as pd
import math 
import numpy as np


product = pd.DataFrame(columns=['col3', 'sincol3'])
product['col3'] = np.random.randn(1000000)
s = pd.Series(product['col3'])
product['sincol3'] = np.sin(s)

performance  = pd.DataFrame(columns=['col1', 'cost'])
performance['col1'] = np.random.randn(1000000)

assortments  = pd.DataFrame(columns=['col2'])
assortments['col2'] = np.random.randn(1000000)

performance['cost'] = performance['col1']+ product['sincol3'] + 2*assortments['col2']

print(performance)
```

It gives you output like:

```
         col1      cost
0       0.194011 -1.940931
1       0.535375  1.891468
```

**Edit after comments**:
You have to understand that the expression on its own do not take a lot of time to calculate. If the expression is the only thing you are doing at run time (given your data frames already have values). Lets compare an example with 50 runs.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import math 
import numpy as np
import time

def cal():
    performance['cost'] = performance['col1']+ product['sincol3'] + 2*assortments['col2']


execution_time = []
product = pd.DataFrame(columns=['col3', 'sincol3'])
product['col3'] = np.random.randn(1000000)
s = pd.Series(product['col3'])
product['sincol3'] = np.sin(s)

performance  = pd.DataFrame(columns=['col1', 'cost'])
performance['col1'] = np.random.randn(1000000)

assortments  = pd.DataFrame(columns=['col2'])
assortments['col2'] = np.random.randn(1000000)

for i in range(0,50):
    start_time = time.time()
    cal()
    execution_time.append(time.time() - start_time)

print('average time taken:\n')
print(np.mean(execution_time))
```

Gives me: `average time taken: 0.15080997943878174`

At the same time:

```
import pandas as pd
import math 
import numpy as np
import time

def cal():
    execution_time = []
    product = pd.DataFrame(columns=['col3', 'sincol3'])
    product['col3'] = np.random.randn(1000000)
    s = pd.Series(product['col3'])
    product['sincol3'] = np.sin(s)

    performance  = pd.DataFrame(columns=['col1', 'cost'])
    performance['col1'] = np.random.randn(1000000)

    assortments  = pd.DataFrame(columns=['col2'])
    assortments['col2'] = np.random.randn(1000000)

    performance['cost'] = performance['col1']+ product['sincol3'] + 2*assortments['col2']

for i in range(0,50):
    start_time = time.time()
    cal()
    execution_time.append(time.time() - start_time)

print('average time taken:\n')
print(np.mean(execution_time))
```

Gives me `average time taken: 0.5624121456611447`

Comment: The above expression is just an example. We need to dynamically parse the expression at run time and
`performance['cost'] = performance['col1']+ product['sincol3'] + 2*assortments['col2']`
for this expression to work some where we need to explicitly tell the foreign key relationship . where should  we mention that

Comment: Could you please give an example to help me understand what you mean at run time parsing and foreign key relationship?

Comment: we are trying to generate a formula builder kind of stuff.
The user will be giving formulas through UI like the one i mentioned above and we need to run those formulas on the panda datasets. All the datasets are inter connected to each other like some sql tables